# How can I group the files in a directory based on their file size

Tags: gnome-terminal, scripts, ls

I have a directory where I am writing lots of files but I know each of them fall under one of the 3 pre-determined memory sizes based on what I write. Any file I write may be either 300KB or 129.1MB or 251MB. Now if there is any packet error in the incoming data, the files that I write will not fall under one of these buckets. Since there will be so many files  generated I will not be able to check the individual file size manually. Hence I need a way by which I can group all files by its size so that most of the files will fall under the three category mentioned above and I can easily find the files that are bad.

In short I want something like this: select file_names from folder and group by file_size. Is it possible?

Edit: It would be even better if anyone can give me a solution by which I can: select file_names from folder whose filesize not in [300KB,129.1MB,251MB]. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort files by size you can use `ls` command with `-S` option:

```
ls -lhS
```

For reverse order, use `-r` option:

```
ls -lhSr
```

I used also `-l` option to use a long listing format, and `-h` option to print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 300KB or 129.1MB or 251MB)

See `man ls` for more info.

Comment: This does what i asked but still I have to scroll a lot to find those that are bad. After asking the question I feel it would be more comfortable if I can do this:select file_names from folder whose file size is not in [300KB,129.1MB,251MB]. Is this possible?

Comment: @VivekVK You can try for example, if you are sure about those sizes: `ls -lhS | grep -vE "300K|129.1M|251M"`

Comment: But why the 'h' option in 'ls' is ceiling 129.1M to 130M??.The command works perfect without it though.

Comment: @VivekVK `-h` - print sizes in human readable format. To see the difference use `ls` with and without this option.